# Cryptography in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, security

I have a Silverlight 4 application that I want to secure. Does Silverlight 4 fully support AES, EH, and RSA?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by secure? Are you referring to messages in transit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no RSA provider in Silverlight.

However, AES is present.

Check [System.Security.Cryptography Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eat8fht%28v=VS.96%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I've written an open source RSA class that works in Silverlight 3, 4 and Windows Phone 7.  Full source is available and no licensing restrictions:
http://scrypt.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

If EH is meant to be DH (Diffie-Hellman) then it looks to me that you want to re-implement SSL. In any case, both these algorithms and complete authentic implementation of SSL/TLS for Silverlight are available in our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-security.php) product.